# Search object array returns full string

Tags: jquery

I have a script that lists movie data, when I search for a movie I get a full string back Eg.

```
[{
    "type": "Rocky",
    "rating": "PG",
    "year": 1982,
    "plot": "Movie plot goes here Rocky rulez",
    "poster": "<a href=\"/image name.jpg\">"
}]
```

I would like to return just the values in seperate divs. All of the examples I have found are on a server. Is this possible without a server? I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tlm2408/kmj60ag0/) here. I am trying to learn jquery, but I'm struggling a bit with it.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What do you mean about 'possible without a server'?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify convert you json to string with all propertys
you dont need that just tell wich property do you want: ***properties.type***

and yor data is not a object. it is a list of object. you have to tell wich object from list do you want to use like that : ***properties[0].type***

the best way. use a loop

```
 for( var i=0; i<properties.length; i++){
    $("#placeHolder").append('<p>'+properties[i].type+'</p>');
 }
```

and use *append* instance of *text*. because *text* replace your new value and you not have access to your old value

**see my code** : https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/ybWoMZ

*be careful* : i added new movie to your data. when you search for *Rambo*, your result is 2 object

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have given me enough to work with.